# Change material angular tab text color

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I cant figure out how the tabs text color is set for the material design extension of angular. There is codepen examples. I can therefore inspect the element and see it is set by some custom style that some how gets injected into the page. How that is configured though escapes me.

My tabs are currently the default color. I have tried modifying $mdThemingProvider but that does not change the text color.

[image]

See:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

[image]

They do exactly what I want in the first example where the tab text changes on selection.

**EDIT**: Obviously I can set the CSS however I want to use the templated colors already configured.

Answer (score 6):

It is preferable to configure the default theme via [`$mdThemingProvider`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme). But, you can override `Angular Material's` default `CSS` classes to achieve your desired result.

> **Tab's background color**

```
md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper {
  background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

> **Tab's text color**

```
md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]) {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

> **Active tab's text color**

```
md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active, md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused md-icon {
  color: #222 !important;
}
```

> **Disabled tab's text color**

```
md-tabs .md-tab[disabled], md-tabs .md-tab[disabled] md-icon {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

To configure via `$mdThemingProvider`, please refer [Angular Material/$mdThemingProvider](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx. I have tried using the mdThemingProvider however I could not change those specific colors

Comment: @Murdock Have you tried above CSS? Is it working in your case?

Comment: Yes it works, but would really like to hook into the templates defined in the material templates.